# Unable to Start Tomcat 7.0 in Eclipse Luna

Tags: mysql, eclipse, jakarta-ee, timeout, tomcat7

I've to start working on a web-app project for which I've Eclipse Luna and Tomcat 7.0 installed. The environment also has JRE 8. But whenever I start the server, it gets timed out!

In the console I get:

```css
nov. 20, 2014 11:08:20 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFOS: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Android;C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\ooc\bin;C:\JacORB1_4\bin;;.
nov. 20, 2014 11:08:21 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
AVERTISSEMENT: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:GestionDesFormationsWebAppMavenized' did not find a matching property.
nov. 20, 2014 11:08:21 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFOS: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
nov. 20, 2014 11:08:21 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFOS: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
nov. 20, 2014 11:08:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFOS: Initialization processed in 567 ms
nov. 20, 2014 11:08:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFOS: Démarrage du service Catalina
nov. 20, 2014 11:08:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFOS: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.56
nov. 20, 2014 11:08:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFOS: Set web app root system property: 'webapp.root' = [C:\Users\Meriem\workspaceJEE\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\GestionDesFormationsWebAppMavenized\]
nov. 20, 2014 11:08:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFOS: Initializing log4j from [classpath:log4j.xml]
nov. 20, 2014 11:08:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFOS: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'spring'
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'spring': initialization started
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'spring-servlet': startup date [Thu Nov 20 23:08:22 WET 2014]; root of context hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - JSR-250 'javax.annotation.ManagedBean' found and supported for component scanning
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer - Loading properties file from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@721bcc07: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,studentController,studentDaoImpl,studentServiceImpl,propertyConfigurer,dataSource,sessionFactory,viewResolver,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,transactionManager]; root of factory hierarchy
```

I have tried the solutions proposed in other questions on this forum like increasing the time out period,changing the port numbers, uninstalling & reinstalling Tomcat, changing the 'publisiing' option for the server but nothing seems to work.

Any help would be sincerely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A timeout means that Tomcat didn't get to the phase where your application has completed starting.  Otherwise, it would have signaled to Eclipse either a success or fail.  Since the last line is about Spring initializing a number of beans, my first thought is you have some post-construct initializer (@PostConstruct, InitializingBean.afterPropertiesSet) that's hanging on an infinite loop or deadlock.

Check your own beans (studentController, studentDaoImpl, studentServiceImpl) for initializers that are hanging.  Maybe create some initializers (use @PostConstruct, it's simpler) and add some logging output to make sure your beans are actually getting initialized.  Failing that you might have to set the timeout to 20-30 minutes or more, get the Spring sources for the version you're using, and actually step through Spring's initialization code.  It looks like it's not even getting to sessionFactory (which I'm assuming is for Hibernate).

Comment: thank you  for the answer, but I tested the same code in another laptop with the same version of tomcat and eclipse and it works.I do not think that the problem in the code.